# Проблема в преобразование из строки в число в телеграмм боте python

Tags: python, telebot

Только начал изучать телеграмм ботов и столкнулся с проблемой когда я отправляю боту сообщение в виде числа, но он преобразуется в текст. И из за этого в коде не могу использовать те данные которые я ввел боту. Сама работа должна заключаться что я ввожу ему данные, а он передвигает мышку по тем координатам которые я указал боту.

**pag это pyautogui**

**Ошибка в строчке -> pag.moveTo(x, y)**

Сама ошибка: **int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'Message'**

```
@client.message_handler(commands=['control'])
def control(message):
    global x
    x = client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите координаты в формате X')
    client.register_next_step_handler(x, next_pos_Y)

def next_pos_Y(message):
    global y
    y = client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите координаты в формате Y')
    client.register_next_step_handler(y, general_move)

def general_move(message):
    pag.moveTo(x, y)
    client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Курсор поменял позицию. Если желаете посмотреть снимок экрана напишите /screenshot')
```

Comment: ```x = client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите координаты в формате X')``` - тут X - не совсем число или строка :) это объект :)

Comment: Понятно, а можно как то сделать чтобы эти объекта передавались как число и я мог их использовать?

Comment: Может быть и можно, что такое ```client.send_message``` - мне доподлинно неизвестно из вашего кода, я вам лишь указал что ошибку ищите не в том месте :)

Comment: Либо мы не ведаем, что творим. вот вам в помощь https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py